# Why doesn't Collection#find work for offline members who have no roles? (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

### My Goal

My goal is to figure out why `Collection#find` returns undefined when I try to find a user in my server, but they're offline and have no roles.

### Expectation

Usually the console logs an array of all the properties of the user

### Actual Result

The console logs `Collection#find`, as undefined if the user in my server is offline and has no roles

### What I've Tried

I've tried using `Collection#get`, but it turns out that it returns the same response. I've tried searching this up on Google, but no one has asked this question before.

### Reproduction Steps

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const {prefix, token} = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Client is online');
  
  const user = client.users.cache.find(user => user.tag === 'Someone#1234');
  console.log(user);
};

client.login(token);
```

Make sure that whoever is helping you, whether it's an alt account or your friend, that they have no roles, and they're completely offline in your server

Output:

> Client is online 
> undefined

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I don't know why this happens, but I used this line to fix that:

```
((await m.guild.members.fetch()).filter(mb => mb.id === "The ID")).first()`
```

Basically, this collect all the members, then filters them with the property you want, and the `first()` at the end is to make it a single object instead of a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `user.tag` property, try using the `user.username` and the `user.discriminator` properties. This worked for me

```js
const user = client.users.cache.find(user => user.username === 'Someone' && user.discriminator === '1234');
```

Also check spelling, capitalization, ect.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, but if it works for you then I'll check if it's a problem on my end and let you know.

Comment: It turns out that the problem only occurs in my server, but I can't figure out what it is. I created a template of the server and created a new one, but I'm not getting the same ``undefined`` response. I added the same bots and gave them the same configuration as well. I would say that the only noticeable difference is the member count.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to my problem is just create an async function and use `await guild.members.fetch()` to cache the users and then use `Collection#find` to get the user.